# strange http redirection loop nginx to glassfish upstream when basic authentication is enabled

Tags: http, nginx, https, glassfish, glassfish-3

I have a cluster glassfish instance running in Ubuntu 12.04 server with nginx as the front-end.
I have configured glassfish upstream in nginx conf file and proxy params are all set.

```
nginx.conf
    glassfish_custer ( upstream name )
```

Now the problem is,

I added a file realm in glassfish with username and password entries to enable basic authentication for one of my applications.
I added necessary login config params in web.xml file, bundled war and deployed in glassfish server and when I fire url,

```
http://domain.com/application
```

It falls in redirect loop

```
https://domain.com/application
```

It happens only when I enable basic authentication. If I switch off, everything is working as expected.

I think I need to set some proxy header params and change auth settings in glassfish admin console for http listener ?

If anyone experienced this issue before, Please let me know....

In short, How to make basic authentication works in nginx load balancer with glassfish as the upstream

**UPDATE 1:
nginx.conf**

```
## http redirects to https ##
server {
    #listen      [::]:80;
    listen      80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
    }

    location @backend {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_set_header x-forwarded-for $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://glassfish_servers;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    # Strict Transport Security
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
    # rewrite ^/.*$ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
    }

     ## default location ##
    location @backend {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass    http://glassfish_servers;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;

    #proxy_http_version 1.1;
    #proxy_set_header Connection "";

    # force timeouts if the backend dies
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

    # set headers
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    #proxy_redirect off;
    }
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain_com.key;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers       on;
    ssl_protocols                   TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers                     ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!$

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Having this xml configuration in web.xml was the root cause of the redirection loop.
Since I added "CONFIDENTIAL" as the authority value, http request were getting redirected to https when request hit backend glassfish instance.
I changed this value to "NONE" and everything worked like charm.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>wholesale</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/acme/wholesale/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>PARTNER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

**Make the following changes**

```
Change <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
```

to

```
<transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
```

Also, make sure to set proper proxy header values in nginx conf file (or) if you configured sites conf files separately in sites-available folder, pls add the following proxy headers

```
proxy_set_header x-forwarded-for $remote_addr;
proxy_intercept_errors on;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```